# Deploy WAR file on Spring - Tomcat 9

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, web, tomcat

I have been tasked with the deploying of a WAR file on Spring boot (or Eclipse or any other IDE). I need to open the server proyect to edit the code and add new http request. Actualy I have no idea how to do this and I have no much information about this task and any solution idea.

I have been able to run the WAR file on Tomcat following this steps:

1. Download the Tomcat 9
2. Execute the .exe and intall the server
3. Paste the WAR file on /webapps
4. Run the server

Tomcat 9 shows this code:

[image]

So I suppose that the IDE I need to deply the WAR file in, is Spring boot v1.3.2

I downloaded Spring Tool Suite 4.9.0 and I install the Tomcat 9 server:

[image]

This is my configuration:

[image]

Now the Tomcat is runing and I can accese to http://localhost:8080/ but I don't know how to continue. I'm trying to import the WAR file to Spring but I don't have the web import option:

[image]

**How could I continue? I made any mistake un to now?**

**Edit:**

I imported the source code into Spring Boot like a Maven proyect. But I can't deployed it on Tomcat server so I deployed it on Boot Dashboard:

[image]

It throws this error:

```
[2021-08-02 13:24:58.041] boot - 15348 ERROR [main] --- 
SpringApplication: Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
at com.noguiana.ws.NoguianaWsApplication.main(NoguianaWsApplication.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:195)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
... 8 more
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.noguiana.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>noguiana-ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>noguiana-ws</name>
    <description>Web server para la gestion de almacen de Noguiana</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jr-ce-releases</id>
            <url>http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**How could I solve this error?**

Comment: A WAR file does not contain Java code, only compiled classes.

Comment: So, How could I descompile the WAR file in Spring?

Comment: I am fairly positive no one asked you to code a new feature without providing the source code. Can you clarify your question: do you need to **deploy** the WAR file on a Tomcat server or add new features to the application?

Comment: I need to add new features to the application and edit the current features. To do it I need to have runing the WAR code on Spring. I have the .java source code. Should I import them insted of the WAR file?

Comment: Yes, import the existing project (source code) into Eclipse. Then you'll be able to choose _"Debug as... > Run on Server"_ from the project's context menu.

Comment: I try to import it and I found it looks more like a Maven project so I deployed it on local Boot Dashboard. I edited the post with the capture of the Spring boot import. It throws an error. I don't know what diferent between deploying on tomcat server or on Boot...

Comment: YOu don't need tomcat. Spring Boot you can just run and execute you don't need an installed tomcat. Find the class with the `main` and just run it.

Comment: On the line: `xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">` of my `pom.xml` says `Missing artifact org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3` what does it mean?

Comment: Google result of https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1184741/3rd-party-repo-down mentions that your repo URL is no longer valid. "[jaspersoft.]artifactoryonline.com has been replaced by jfrog.io, you need to change the http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifa... repository in your project to https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"

Comment: @nitind I'm sorry I don't know what do you mean. I don't know what I have to do.